# How is it possible to modify columns heading in invoice

Tags: invoice

In the first invoice table I would like to change "Activity" to "Description" and just have "Total" without the "Sum Fees" line.

In the second invoice table I would like to change "Expense" to "Account #" and the other column should be "Amount (Dollar)" without "Currency", "Amount" and "Factor".

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{invoice}


\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{}
    \opening{Invoice no. 1}

    My greeting
    \begin{invoice}{Dollar}{0}{9}
      \ProjectTitle{Example Project}%
      % Description    Rate/Unit   Count    Amount ()
      \Fee{Development} {3000.00} {1}

    \end{invoice}

    \begin{invoice}{Dollar}{0}{9}
      \ProjectTitle{Account number(s)}%
      % Account #      Amount (Dollar)
      \EBC{1273645923} {1000}
      \EBC{2734745394} {2000}      
    \end{invoice}


  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're planning on making such major changes to an archaic package, you may just as well write the invoices yourself using a `tabular`-like approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{
  round-integer-to-decimal,
  round-mode = places,
  detect-weight = true,
  detect-inline-weight = text
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \large\bfseries Example Project
\end{center}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X r r r}
  \toprule
  \bfseries Activity & Rate/Unit & Count & Amount (Dollar) \\
  \midrule
  Development              & \num{3000} & 1 & \num{3000} \\
  \bottomrule
  \bfseries Total          &            &   & \bfseries\num{3000}
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{center}
  \large\bfseries Account number(s)
\end{center}

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X r}
  \toprule
  \bfseries Expense & Amount (Dollar) \\
  \midrule
  1273645923 & \num{1000} \\
  2734745394 & \num{2000} \\
  \bottomrule
  \bfseries Total & \bfseries\num{\calc{1000+2000}}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Updating the output provided by `invoice` would require a number of macros to be changed verbatim which yields so much extra code in the preamble. That much code might just as well be replaced by something that suits your needs completely, is clean-looking and can be easily update.

Original output under [`invoice`](http://ctan.org/pkg/invoice):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{invoice}

\renewcommand{\Activity}{Description}
\renewcommand{\Expense}{Account \#}
\renewcommand{\Amount}{}
\renewcommand{\Factor}{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{}
    \opening{Invoice no. 1}

    My greeting


    \begin{invoice}{Dollar}{0}
      \ProjectTitle{Example Project}%
      % Description    Rate/Unit   Count    Amount ()
      \Fee{Development} {3000.00} {1}

    \end{invoice}


    \begin{invoice}{Dollar}{0}
      \ProjectTitle{Account number(s)}%
      % Account #      Amount (Dollar)
      \EBC{1273645923} {1000}
      \EBC{2734745394} {2000}      
    \end{invoice}


  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: image of invoice]

Note that the `invoice` environment only has two arguments. I'm not sure if you intended it, but your code produces a spurious 9 from

```
\begin{invoice}{Dollar}{0}{9}
```