# Can't get rid of the parentheses! LaTeX invoice package

Tags: invoice

I am trying to write an invoice in LaTeX using the `invoice` package. However, I do not want there to be a currency or parentheses after "amount". I can easily get rid of the currency by leaving the field blank, but I have been unable to remove the parentheses.

My code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}
\address{Name\\Business\\etc.}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Customer name }
\opening{}

\begin{invoice}{}{0}
  \ProjectTitle{Invoice}
  \Fee{Example} {25.99} {1}
\end{invoice}

\closing{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

This gives me:

[image]

As I said above, I am trying to remove the parentheses after "amount".

Comment: does this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289246/how-is-it-possible-to-modify-columns-heading-in-invoice ?

Comment: @naphaneal My bad. When I copied and pasted the code it got put in twice. I just edited the question to fix it. As for the other question it seems they get around it by making their own table instead of using the invoice's table. I would like to avoid making my own table if possible.

Comment: Specify the base currency. E.g., `\begin{invoice}{USD}{0}`. (This doesn't remove the parentheses because they are hard-wired into the command and must enclose the base currency. Fully removing them would mean hacking the command.)

Comment: @jon How would one go about "hacking the command"

Comment: Looks like two people already answered it. If it were me, however, I'd probably just leave it in. After all, you still need to include the empty argument (i.e., the `{}` from your example).

Comment: Just curious why would one not want to have the currency indicated? Cause this can be anything 25.99 apples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the parentheses you have to redefine the internal `\Fee@Title` command:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}
\address{Name\\Business\\etc.}

\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Fee@Title}{%
    \\
    \noindent\textbf{\Activity}&&\UnitRate&\Count&\Amount\\% removed part in parentheses here
    \hline%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Customer name }
\opening{}


\begin{invoice}{}{0}
  \ProjectTitle{Invoice}
  \Fee{Example} {25.99} {1}
\end{invoice}

\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The first argument for the `invoice` environment is used to specify the `B`ase `C`urrency (or `\BC`) and is placed after `Amount` automatically. Either redefine `\Fee@Title` - the macro responsible for setting the header in the invoice table, or patch it via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Fee@Title}{\ (\BC)}{}{}{}% Remove "\ (\BC)" from \Fee@Title
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}

\address{Name\\Business\\etc.}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Fee@Title}{\ (\BC)}{}{}{}% Remove "\ (\BC)" from \Fee@Title
\makeatother

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Customer name }
\opening{}

\begin{invoice}{}{0}
  \ProjectTitle{Invoice}
  \Fee{Example} {25.99} {1}
\end{invoice}

\closing{Thanks}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```